# How to set alpha in R?

Tags: r, statistics, variable-assignment

I have [this example](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/coin/html/LocationTests.html) from the coin package of R:

```
  library(coin)
  library(multcomp)
  ### Length of YOY Gizzard Shad from Kokosing Lake, Ohio,
  ### sampled in Summer 1984, Hollander & Wolfe (1999), Table 6.3, page 200
  YOY <- data.frame(length = c(46, 28, 46, 37, 32, 41, 42, 45, 38, 44, 
                               42, 60, 32, 42, 45, 58, 27, 51, 42, 52, 
                               38, 33, 26, 25, 28, 28, 26, 27, 27, 27, 
                               31, 30, 27, 29, 30, 25, 25, 24, 27, 30),
                    site = factor(c(rep("I", 10), rep("II", 10),
                                    rep("III", 10), rep("IV", 10))))

  ### Nemenyi-Damico-Wolfe-Dunn test (joint ranking)
  ### Hollander & Wolfe (1999), page 244 
  ### (where Steel-Dwass results are given)
  NDWD <- oneway_test(length ~ site, data = YOY,
      ytrafo = function(data) trafo(data, numeric_trafo = rank),
      xtrafo = function(data) trafo(data, factor_trafo = function(x)
          model.matrix(~x - 1) %*% t(contrMat(table(x), "Tukey"))),
      teststat = "max", distribution = approximate(B = 90000))

  ### global p-value
  print(pvalue(NDWD))

  ### sites (I = II) != (III = IV) at alpha = 0.01 (page 244)
  print(pvalue(NDWD, method = "single-step"))
```

I want to assign alpha a different value, how can I do this??

This doesn't work!

```
  library(coin)
  library(multcomp)
  ### Length of YOY Gizzard Shad from Kokosing Lake, Ohio,
  ### sampled in Summer 1984, Hollander & Wolfe (1999), Table 6.3, page 200
  YOY <- data.frame(length = c(46, 28, 46, 37, 32, 41, 42, 45, 38, 44, 
                               42, 60, 32, 42, 45, 58, 27, 51, 42, 52, 
                               38, 33, 26, 25, 28, 28, 26, 27, 27, 27, 
                               31, 30, 27, 29, 30, 25, 25, 24, 27, 30),
                    site = factor(c(rep("I", 10), rep("II", 10),
                                    rep("III", 10), rep("IV", 10))))

  ### Nemenyi-Damico-Wolfe-Dunn test (joint ranking)
  ### Hollander & Wolfe (1999), page 244 
  ### (where Steel-Dwass results are given)
  NDWD <- oneway_test(length ~ site, data = YOY,
      ytrafo = function(data) trafo(data, numeric_trafo = rank),
      xtrafo = function(data) trafo(data, factor_trafo = function(x)
          model.matrix(~x - 1) %*% t(contrMat(table(x), "Tukey"))),
      teststat = "max", distribution = approximate(B = 90000),
      alpha = 0.05)

  ### global p-value
  print(pvalue(NDWD))

  ### sites (I = II) != (III = IV) at alpha = 0.05 (default was 0.01) (page 244)
  print(pvalue(NDWD, method = "single-step"))
```

Comment: Maybe you should change the title of this question: 'alpha' can mean a different number of things in R, for example, I tought you were talking about the transparency of the points in a plot.

Comment: conf.level will give us a varied value but different alpha values should give different p-values as well. which doesnt happen by changing conflevel value. There should be some method to change alpha value sig.level also doesnot work. kindly help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The alpha levels are hardcoded and fixed at 0.99 If you want to change that, then you have to download the package source, change the levels and compile the package. The levels are coded in the Methods.R file. Search for binom.test or conf.level

You could ask the package author to change the package so you can set the level yourself. But bear in mind that the package author is not obliged to do that!

Comment: so if I want to set alpha to 0.05 as was intended, I need to change conf.levels to 0.95? is that right?

Comment: Yep. The confidence level is (1 - alpha)

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that you cannot: `oneway_test()` has no argument `conf.level` whereas `wilcox_test` and `normal_test` do. This is all documented, see `help(oneway_test)`.

Comment: but they say in the original example alpha = 0.01, how do they set if I cannot?

Comment: [link to example](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/coin/html/LocationTests.html)

Comment: This is open source, so may I suggest you read the source?  

I was simply pointing out to you that the _documented_ interface does not support it.

Comment: I already downloaded and tried to read the source but there was no mention of a matching-named variable/symbol in the sources o__O So I now think that alpha may be something that goes under different names in the comment and code.

Comment: I haven't looked at the source, but sometimes you use sigma rather than alpha. That's not to say that alpha _is_ sigma, but you can convert from one to the other.